# Can Parademons retain the original being's abilities?

Tags: dc, comics

In the DC universe (and multi-verse), Parademons are Darkseid's personal troops for conquest. Although various descriptions have been provided about them across the Internet, one thing is common:

> Parademons are sentient species captured and genetically modified by Darkseid's scientists to serve Darkseid's will.

They have been known to show several abilities, including super-human strength, capability of flight, etc. (both in the comics and in the recent *Justice League* movie).

My question is: When certain beings (human, alien, or otherwise) are turned into parademons, do they retain any abilities they possessed before? For the sake of an example, lets say that The FL was turned into a parademon. Would he still retain his super-speed and the connection to the Speed Force?

As there is very little information about the parademons in the *Justice League* movie, I base my question purely on the DC comic books and the DC animated versions.

Comment: In Justice League War Darkseid's scientist is excited at the opportunity to turn a Kryptonian into a Parademon. That at least suggests that some beings make more powerful Parademons than others, but it does not say (as far as I remember) that the power set would be the same as in the original Superman.

Comment: @EikePierstorff yeah. I remembered how Desaad experiments on Superman. Like you said, that was my first guess too.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to provide an answer based on going back to the earliest sources describing parademons, Jack Kirby's *Fourth World* comics.  Note, however, that this means sources from before the notion that parademons could be formed out of other beings.

Between *New Gods* #7 ("The Pact"), which revealed how Orion and Scott Free were exchanged between Apokalips and New Genesis, and *Mister Miracle* #10 ("Himon"), which told the story of how Scott Free escaped from Granny Goodness's battle school, *Mister Miracle* #7-9 ran vignettes about "Young Scott Free."  These told of his youth on Apokalips, leading up to his escape in issue #10.  The last vignette, in issue #9, showed Scott besting a parademon in combat, foreshadowing Scott's possession of a Mother Box, which aided him in the fight.

After the fight, the observers are amazed by "a fledgeling besting a seasoned parademon."  This appears to indicate that parademons had a predictable level of power.  The powers of the parademons were thus not widely divergent, depending on how each parademon was created.